# Kinesis :: bounding boxes on aws kinesis live video stream and play the video from front-end react.js app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, detection, amazon-rekognition, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am working on an application which will detect faces from live stream. I have a front-end application in react.js and backend is serverless AWS which will call `rekognition` api to detect faces and return co-ordinates of bounding boxes of the detected faces. My video source is aws `kinesis` video stream.

In UI, `ReactPlayer` is being used to play the video from `hlsurl`. Now my question is, how can I draw `bounding boxes` on detected faces/mask on the real time stream and show the video from UI?

my approach:

return bounding-boxes from a `lambda` function and draw using html canvas, but due to latency it won't give the feel of real time detection.

So, how can I show the kinesis real time video stream with `bounding` `boxes` is there any other approach to follow? I have gone through the documentations but those are for static images only.